# Using SQLite in a UWP with MVVMCross

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite, uwp, mvvmcross

I'm trying to use SQLite in an MVVMCross UWP app; however, as soon as I try to resolve the registered instance of my data access layer, I get the following error:

> Exception thrown: 'System.IO.FileLoadException' in MyApp.Core.dll
>
> Additional information: Could not load file or assembly 'SQLite.Net,
>   Version=3.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its
>   dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not
>   match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Here is where it crashes:

```
 private void AddProduct()
 {
     ICrudEntityDataAccess da = Mvx.Resolve<ICrudEntityDataAccess>();
     da.Create<Product>(Product); // Runtime error
 }
```

The UWP app references the Nuget package:

> SQLite.Net.Platform.WinRT

And the core app references:

> SQLite.Net.Core-PCL

And

> Sqlite.Net-PCL

The are registered here:

```
protected override void InitializeFirstChance()
{
    base.InitializeFirstChance();

    MvxSimpleIoCContainer.Instance.RegisterSingleton<IPlatformSpecific>(
        new PlatformSpecific()
        {
            LocalFolderPath = 
                Path.Combine(Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path,
                "db.sqlite")
        });

    MvxSimpleIoCContainer.Instance.RegisterSingleton<ISQLitePlatform>(
        new SQLitePlatformWinRT());
```

Clearly I've missed a key part of this (I'm guessing with relation to which NuGet packages are required for which projects.  Please could someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because SQLite is not provided by default in contrast to iOS and Android, you need to install and add a reference to the SQLite for Universal Windows Platform package manually. This is actually a great thing, because you can always have the latest and greatest version!

Download and install the extension from [here](http://sqlite.org/download.html) - get the latest version under the **Universal Windows Platform** heading.

Restart Visual Studio, right click your UWP project in Solution Explorer, select `Add - Reference`. In the **Add reference** dialog window select `Universal Windows - Extensions` in the left sidebar and check the box for `SQLite for Universal Windows Platform` in the list of extensions.

This should hopefully help fix your problem.

Comment: I tried this and, initially, it made no difference.  What I ended up doing was removing the Nuget references and re-adding them; which did work.  Many thanks.